# wxPython and py2app on Mac OSX Lion: can't import wx

Tags: wxpython, osx-lion, py2app

I need to create a standalone python app with wxPython, to work with Mac OSX Lion (the client's OS).
I only have access to a Mac with Snow Leopard, and used it to build the app with py2app. With Snow Leopard it works fine, and didn't even have to install wxPython.

On a OSX Lion however, the wx import fails (no module found), even after installing the wxPython for python2.7 (Carbon). I can import wx from the terminal (using the default python - 2.7), but the app still fails to find wx on import.

I used the following setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['main.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'arch': 'i386', 'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

And compiled it using `arch -i386 /usr/bin/python2.6 setup.py py2app`, to be able to run it on 32-bit.

What's the best way to make it run on Lion, compiling on Snow Leopard? Could I include the wxPython with the app, or even python itself (in case it really needs to run with py2.6)? Can I order the application to run /usr/bin/python2.6?

Comment: Do you have 32-bit wxPython installed? Do you have Python 2.7.3 Mac OS X 64-bit/32-bit x86-64/i386 Installer (for Mac OS X 10.6 and 10.7) installed?

Comment: @Craig On the snow leopard I just use the wxPython that comes with the OS, that can be imported when running python on 32bit mode. I wish to be able to distribute an app without installing any software on a client's Lion.

Comment: Python has two binaries you can install: one binary is for OSX 10.3 to 10.6, the other is for 10.6 and 10.7. Your Snow Leopard machine must have the 10.6/10.7 binary, which is called the "Python 2.7.3 Mac OS X 64-bit/32-bit x86-64/i386 Installer" on the downloads.python.org website.

Comment: @Craig And will I need to install that python distro on each client's computer, or will it run using Lion's own python2.7?

Comment: You won't need Python or wxPython installed on the client computer. You'll just have a really big app that contains both (50 Meg or so). The trick to building apps that run on different OS versions is that the machine doing the building must have versions of Python and wxPython that are compatible with both OSes.

Comment: Thanks, @Craig. Is my setup.py OK for that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11816/discussion-between-craig-and-jpimentel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the chat discussion, use the latest stable versions of Python and wxPython, and make sure the Python is the OS X 10.6 and 10.7 version. (And don't try to build them from source.)